# Python Stuck Calculating

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, calculus

I am trying to solve a problem using python, and I need to calculate :
`r =(1^2|~4)**((5&9^3)|3*8**9)`

However, the computer is taking forever to finish that operation. Any clue on how to solve this?

Simpler = `-5**402653186`

SPECS :

**OS : Ubuntu 18.04**

**RAM : 8 Gig**

**CPU : Intel i5 8Gen**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you're trying to calculate is very large. -1.45992917087860574535892544169158544350135939488 × 10^281442499 to be precise according to wolfram-alpha. While python longs can be of unlimited length and expand to fill memory it is just a calculation that would take a super long time, try using htop, it should show that ram usage is constantly increasing. You should reconsider on why you are calculating numbers so large.

Comment: Hampton Moore is quite right. You're using the wrong tool for the task at hand (or possibly have specified the wrong task). You might be happier using this library: https://gmplib.org/